# SQL Generating one string from all columns

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to create a separate log table, made from insert trigger values using now. The table has a lot of columns, so I was wondering if it is possible to convert all values of the row to one string.

Sample working code with two columns:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TEST` AFTER INSERT ON `table` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO change_log (string)
       VALUES (CONCAT("User: ", USER(), " Time: ", NOW(), " Insert: " , now.id, now.value));
    END
```

Comment: You already do it!? Just stuff them all into `concat()`. As long as it all can be implicitly cast to a `varchar` you'll end up with a concatenation of the string representations of all column values. Or is your question about how do retrieve the columns from the catalog and dynamically build an `INSERT` statement?

Comment: The table I'm working with has 56 columns. As a lazy person I think that there should be an easier solution other than writing all 56 column names. What do you mean by dynamically build `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of columns from the catalog. You can (group) concatenate them to form a concatenation expression.

```
SELECT concat('concat(',
              group_concat(concat('''',
                                  column_name,
                                  ': '', ',
                                  column_name)
                           SEPARATOR ', '),
              ')')
       FROM information_schema.columns
       WHERE table_schema = '<schema name>'
             AND table_name = '<table name>';
```

(Replace `<schema name>` and `<table name>` with your table's name and its schema.)

That will give you an expression like `concat('a: ', a, 'b: ', b, 'c: ', c)` (if the column name were `a`, `b` and `c`).

Amend the result to include your meta data (user, time, etc.) and copy it into your trigger.

Or, if you want, you could also call the query from the catalog in your trigger. Amend it, so that in the trigger a string is built which holds the statement you want to execute and execute it with `PREPARE ... EXECUTE ... DEALLOCATE PREPARE ...` or `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ...` (which is essentially shorthand for the former). More information on dynamic SQL in MariaDB can be found in ["Prepared Statements "](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/prepared-statements/).

Answer (score 0):

Use your application language to build a JSON string -- which is very similar to what you are doing, except that it also takes care of embedded quotes and backslashes.